# How to implement tokio_postgres::types::ToSql for enum type (rust, postgres)

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres

I need to implement the tokio_postgres::types::ToSql for an enum type (rust and db as enum implemented) and I had no idea how to ...

Example

```rust
enum Flag {MyFlag1, MyFlag2, MyFlag3};
// on postgres db :
//    CREATE TYPE flag AS ENUM ('my_flag_1', 'my_flag_2', 'my_flag_3');

impl ToSql for Flag {
  fn to_sql(&self, ty: &Type, out: &mut BytesMut) -> Result<IsNull, Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send>> {
    // ???
  }
  fn accepts(ty: &Type) -> bool {
    // ???
  }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

From the [`postgres-types` documentation](https://docs.rs/postgres-types/latest/postgres_types/#enums) (which both `tokio-postgres` and `postgres` are based on so this will work for both crates):

Postgres enums correspond to C-like enums in Rust:

```sql
CREATE TYPE "Mood" AS ENUM (
    'Sad',
    'Ok',
    'Happy'
);
```

```rust
use postgres_types::{ToSql, FromSql};

#[derive(Debug, ToSql, FromSql)]
enum Mood {
    Sad,
    Ok,
    Happy,
}
```

and for [naming](https://docs.rs/postgres-types/latest/postgres_types/#naming):

You can use `#[postgres(name = "flag")]` to adjust the enum name and `rename_all = "snake_case"` to adjust the variant names (for more extensive information see the docs I linked). In your case the final code would look like this:

```rust
// tokio_postgres reexports postgres_types as the types module
use tokio_postgres::types::ToSql;

#[derive(Debug, ToSql)] // ToSql requires Debug
#[postgres(name = "flag", rename_all = "snake_case")]
enum Flag {
    MyFlag1, 
    MyFlag2, 
    MyFlag3
}
```

This will correctly parse your postgres enum created with

```sql
CREATE TYPE flag AS ENUM ('my_flag_1', 'my_flag_2', 'my_flag_3');
```